# How Can I Redirect to My Site's Root In a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm writing a bit of code to do the login logic for my website. Basically what I want to do is redirect a user who clicked the logout to the home page. Unfortunately, my home page is a splash html page so it doesn't show up in Rails' routing scheme. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I handle this by serving up static pages as resources from Rails just the same everything else. So http://railsroot/pages/home would display a static home page.

I use the [High Voltage](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage) gem from Thoughtbot to make this simple to achieve.  You can then just redirect to your page using:

```
page_path('home')
```

Comment: I don't love the idea of having an extra gem, but this looks like a promising solution.

Comment: What I would really like is to be able to redirect_to http://www.myapp.com, this seems like I will only be able to redirect_to http://www.myapp.com/pages/home. Is that correct?

Comment: You can set the root of your app to be /pages/home in the same way as Axsuul has indicated.  Using the High Voltage method has the advantage that you can reuse your layouts for things like headers and sometimes even static pages could use a little bit of dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Define your root in your `routes.rb` as

```
root :to => "main#index"
```

which will go to your `MainController#index` for example. Then, to redirect to it

```
redirect_to root_path
```